# Reading a CByteArray from the registry

Tags: mfc

For some reason I think I have over complicated this.

This is my saving code:

```
theApp.WriteProfileBinary(theApp.GetActiveScheduleSection(_T("Options")), _T("AssignStates"),
    rAryByAssignStates.GetData(), sizeof(BYTE) * (UINT)iNumColumns);
```

Short and sweet.

This is my reading code:

```
void COptionsDlg::ReadAssignStatesInfoEx(CByteArray& rbyAryAutoAssignStates)
{
    UINT uSize;
    LPBYTE  ppData = NULL;
    BYTE *pbyAssignStates = NULL;

    theApp.GetProfileBinary(theApp.GetActiveScheduleSection(_T("Options")), _T("AssignStates"), &ppData, &uSize);
    if (uSize > 0)
    {
        // In theory it should be safe to use this data
        pbyAssignStates = new BYTE[uSize];
        memcpy(pbyAssignStates, ppData, uSize);

        rbyAryAutoAssignStates.SetSize(uSize);
        for (UINT i = 0; i < uSize; i++)
            rbyAryAutoAssignStates[i] = pbyAssignStates[i];

        delete[] pbyAssignStates;
        pbyAssignStates = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        // It seems like the user has not yet displayed the Options window
        RebuildAssignStatesInfoEx(rbyAryAutoAssignStates, true);
    }

    // Tidy memory
    if (uSize != 0)
    {
        delete[] ppData;
        ppData = NULL;
    }
}
```

It works. But have I overdone this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I got it:

```
rbyAryAutoAssignStates.SetSize(uSize);
memcpy(rbyAryAutoAssignStates.GetData(), ppData, uSize);
```

This helped. See [info](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/CLYbhAi6tJ8)